# Why do I get the same value from iterating over this hash?

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, get, put

I'm trying to put a hash `%listvol` into an array `@fileInfo` in Perl.

```
@fileInfo = ($filename, $data, $index, \%listvol);
```

`%listvol` contains a list of volume: key = `$vol`, value = `$vol`.
The first `$vol` values are `ABCDEF`, then `GFFFF`, `EEEAA` - always different.

Then I put the array `@fileInfo` in the hash `%listeAllFile`:

```
$listeAllFile{$nameOfFile} = [@fileInfo];
```

Later I'm trying to get the hash `%listvol` without success. I'm using this code:

```
foreach $key (keys %listeAllFile) {
    @tab      = @{ $listeAllFile{$key} };
    $filename = $tab[0];
    %listvol  = %{ $tab[3] };
    foreach $vol (keys %listvol) {
        print "\n vol is $vol for file $filename";
    }
```

The file name is always different, so it is ok. But the value of the variable `$vol` is always the same, `ABCDEF`. It seems that I get get each time the same value.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: [Works for me.](http://paste.scsys.co.uk/197007?ln=on&hl=on) You have something left out in your problem description, and the problem must be hiding there. - [Edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/10548834/edit) to [provide a full runnable program that exhibits the problem](http://sscce.org), including assignment of example data to the relevant variables.

Comment: Looks like you are not using `use strict`, Patrick. If you had, this problem might have been avoided by using lexical variables with reduced scope, instead of global ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you didn't include code to reproduce your problem, I'm fairly sure that the issue is that you're storing a reference to the same `%listvol` hash in each array.

When you change the contents of `%listvol` for the second entry, you're modifying the first entry at the same time.  One way to fix that is to use `{%listvol}` instead of `\%listvol`.  The former makes a shallow copy of the current contents of `%listvol`, just like `[@fileInfo]` makes a shallow copy of the current contents of `@fileInfo`.

Comment: ok .You were right, %listvol probably use the same pointer.  It works perfect with {%listvol} . Thank you very much.